# Groovy code to read rabbitMQ working on Windows, not working on Linux

Tags: groovy, rabbitmq, apache-nifi

**Need:** Read from rabbitMQ with AMQPS

**Problem:** ConsumeAMQP is not working so I'm using groovy script that's working on windows and not working on linux.  Error message is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.setUri() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [amqps://user:xxxxxxxXXXxxxx@c-s565c7-ag77-etc-etc-etc.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671/virtualhost]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), every(), every(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

**Troubleshooting:**
Developed code on python to test from my machine using pika lib and it's working with URL amqps. It reads from rabbitMQ. no connection issues.
put the python code on the nifi server (1.15.3) machine, installed python and pika lib, execute on the command line, it's working on the server and reads from rabbitMQ.

Develop groovy code to test from my windows apache nifi (1.15.3)` and it's working, it's reading from rabbitMQ client system.

Copy the code (copy past) to the nifi server, uploaded the .jar lib also. Not working with this error message. create a groovy file and execute the code. not working.

Can anyone help me?

**NOTE:** I want to use groovy code to output the results to the flowfile.

```
@Grab('com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:5.14.2')

import com.rabbitmq.client.*
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.*


// -- Define connection 
def ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setUri('amqps://user:password@a-r5t60-etc-etc-etc.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671/virtualhost');
factory.useSslProtocol();
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();


// -- Waiting for messages.");

boolean noAck = false;
int count = 0;

while(count<10) {

    GetResponse response = channel.basicGet("db-user-q" , noAck) 

    if (response != null) {
        byte[] body = response.getBody()
        long deliveryTag = response.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag()
        def msg = new String(body, "UTF-8")
        channel.basicAck(response.envelope.deliveryTag, false)

        def flowFile = session.create()
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'myAttr', msg)
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
        
    } 
    count++;
}


channel.close();
connection.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code is suspect:

```
def ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
```

You don't need both `def` and a type `ConnectionFactory`.  Just change it to this:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory()
```

You don't need the semi-colon either.  The keyword `def` is used for dynamic typing situations (or laziness), and specifying the type (ie `ConnectionFactory`) is for static typing situations.  You can't have both.  It's either dynamic or static typing.  I suspect Groovy VM is confused by what type the object is hence why it can't figure out if `setUri` exists or not.

Comment: you CAN use `def` and type in Groovy. It might be not nice, but definitely not a reason for a compile error.

Comment: I'd try removing it and see if it works.  Given this is a Java class being used some "features" of Groovy don't always behave nicely.  I bet this is one of those situations even while technically def and type MIGHT be allowed.  In practice I've run into lots of situations where the Groovy complier/interpreter will allow syntax, but throws strange exceptions that seeming have nothing to do with the problem.  If I change the syntax to be more straight forward the exception goes away.